# Sprite won't travel properly to a point

Tags: xna-4.0, movement

I am creating a game in which I would like the player to be able to click a location and have the character travel to it. This is the code I am trying to use for this:

```
if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevMouse == ButtonState.Released)
{
    travelTo = new Point(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y);
}
if (travelTo.X >= 0 && travelTo.Y >= 0)
{
    if (Bounds.Y < travelTo.Y)        {
        if (Bounds.X < travelTo.X)
            destRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians((float)Math.Atan((Bounds.Y - travelTo.Y) / (Bounds.X - travelTo.X)));
        else if (Bounds.X > travelTo.X)
            destRadians = 90 + MathHelper.ToRadians((float)Math.Atan((Bounds.X - travelTo.X) / (Bounds.Y - travelTo.Y)));
        else if (Bounds.X == travelTo.X)
            destRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(90);
    }
    else if (Bounds.Y < travelTo.Y)
    {
        if (Bounds.X < travelTo.X)
            destRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(-1 * (float)(Math.Atan((Bounds.Y - travelTo.Y) / (Bounds.X - travelTo.X))));
        else if (Bounds.X > travelTo.X)
            destRadians = 180 - MathHelper.ToRadians((float)(Math.Atan((Bounds.Y - travelTo.Y) / (Bounds.X - travelTo.X))));
        else if (Bounds.X == travelTo.Y)
            destRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(-90);
    }
    else if (Bounds.Y == travelTo.Y)
    {
        if (Bounds.X < travelTo.X)
            destRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(0);
        else if (Bounds.X > travelTo.X)
            destRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(180);
        else if (Bounds.X == travelTo.X)
            travelTo = new Point(-1, -1);
    }

    //turn the sprite
    if (radians < destRadians)
    {
        radians += .06f;
    }
    else if (radians > destRadians)
    {
        radians -= .06f;
    }

    //move sprite
    Bounds.Offset((int)(2.5f * (float)(Math.Cos(radians))), (int)(2.5f * (float)(Math.Sin(radians))));

    //remove the destination if the player is close enough
    if (Bounds.Intersects(new Rectangle(travelTo.X, travelTo.Y, 1, 1)))
        travelTo = new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

What I want to happen is for the sprite to do two things each game loop: Turn toward the destination a little if it is not already pointed there, and move forward a little.

Right now what happens is this:

When the destination is above the sprite, it continually moves straight across the screen to the right (0 radians).

When the destination is below and to the left of the sprite, it turns around in a continuous circle.

When the destination is below and to the right, the sprite travels straight accross to the right until it is directly above the destination, then turns and proceeds down in a series of semicircles until it reaches the destination point.

Comment: Look into linear interpolation, your life will be a LOT easier, that code looks too much when you could do it in two lines with interpolation (it is usually called lerp).

Comment: From what I can understand of linear interpolation, it would translate the player along the linear interpolant between it's location and the destination. However, since the direction the player is facing matters, what I would like to do is turn it toward the destination point while translating it in the direction it is looking. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: You can do spherical interpolation which is also part of the common graphics libraries. (If you are using quaternions for rotations that is) If you rotate using yaw-pitch-roll, you can get away with linear interpolation for rotations I guess, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: I rotate by storing a float value `radians` and using the overloaded `spriteBatch.Draw()` method that takes a parameter for rotation. Would the methods you suggested work for a 2D game?

Comment: This method is widely used among 2D (and any, really) games.